# using php to check if a file is a kml file

Tags: php, kml

I am using move_file_upload on my server side in php so that client can allow users to upload their kml files to the server. I know that in order to check an image , in php I can use `$check = getimagesize(file)` but what would be the equivalent for a kml file check ?

I donot want to just check the extension of the file. I wish to know if infact the file is a valid kml file or not. If I only check the extension, someone can just post some other malicious file and change its extension to .kml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if the file has the *extension* KML, you can use:

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; //or however you are getting the filename
$ext = end((explode(".",$filename)));

if($ext!="kml"){
    //Extension is incorrect
}
```

Comment: I know about extension, but just checking the extension is a very weak security procedure dont you think?

Comment: Well you can change the extension of a file without affecting the contents - there isn't much more you can do to verify whether the file is a valid KML file.

Comment: what about opening the file in server side and checking if it has kml tags in it? like <kml/> <Placemark/> etc?

Answer (score 0):

Checking mime content can be helpful.
I am not quite sure what is the correct mime name of kml files but at least with checking in google it should be something as:

```
mime_content_type ($file) === 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
```

How ever its possible that there are mimes set to 'application/xml' or 'text/xml' so extension validation is required as well ..

Comment: A KML file exported from Google Maps simply returns "application/xml" from mime_content_type()